# Is the phrase "to suck something out of something" grammatically correct?

Tags: prepositions, phrases

Is the phrase "to suck something out of something", as in "this remedy sucks all toxin out of your body" grammatically correct?

Comment: It is grammatical. Why do you think otherwise?

Comment: I second that - why do you think that it’s not? BTW your example is missing words, though, and is ungrammatical as it stands.

Comment: An example: "This vacuum pump sucks all the air from the cooling coils." "Removes" might be a better choice, in some cases.